# How to do command line search for duplicate downloads within downloads folder?

Tags: command-line, downloads, search, duplicate

I'm looking to do a command line search for duplicate downloads within my `Downloads` folder.

Let say I download `test.mp3`, but then accidentally download it again, the 2nd download will show up as `test(1).mp3`.  I want to search for any file that has "(1)" at the end of the file name, but before the file extension.  What would the command to do this be?

Comment: `ls ~/Download/*\([1-9]\).mp3` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
for f in ~/Downloads/*; do
    if [[ $f == *\([1-9]\).* ]]; then
        echo "$f"
    fi
done
```

- **Edit**: @steeldriver pointed out that globs can do the above, so the simpler solution is this:

  ```
  printf '%s\n' ~/Downloads/*\([1-9]\).*
  ```

I prefer plain Bash, but you could do this in one line using `find`:

```
find ~/Downloads/ -name '*\([1-9]\).*'
```

Comment: Awesome thank you that works!  Do you happen to know the `find` command to do it as well?  I was trying at first before asking here to do it in `find` but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: For a single digit, does regex offer any advantage over a simple glob (`echo ~/Downloads/*\([1-9]\).*` or `find ~/Downloads -name '*\([1-9]\).*'`)?

Comment: @steeldriver Wow, those are way smoother! I'll put those in my answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively we can calculate the checksums and print the duplicated (this is independent of the download duplicated name conventions).

```
md5sum ~/Download/*.mp3 | awk 'a[$1]{print $2 }{ a[$1]=$2}'
```